# Using open function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used the open function to print out the file handle of a notepad file. The problem is the encoding of the notepad file is 'UTF-8'. But the file handle shows 'cp1252'. Why is there a difference?

[image: notepad]

[image: after executing]

[image: code]

Comment: cp1252 is the windows system default encoding. You can set the encoding when you open the file. 
Please can you put code in your question

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Well, don't add code as *images*! That's way more inconvenient than just posting it as text (and formaated as "code" of course).

Comment: Oh I got my answer. I just have to specify the encoding type. I'm totally new to coding so this might sound dumb